# Unneccesary header added for uploaded file by PUT or POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I mmake file upload API with this document `https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser`

in `view.py`

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        entry = WaveFile(document=file_obj) 
        entry.save()
        return Response(status=204)
```

and then make url in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())
]
```

and model is like this below

```
class WaveFile(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='@_mat/_spleeter_wav/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I can send the file as `PUT` like this `curl -X PUT -F upfile=_mat/e_h_01.jpg http://localhost:8008/upload/e_h_01.jpg`

However uploaded file is broken because there is unnecessary file header is attached to the file.

```
--------------------------02d173694176f7aa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="e_h_01.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Why this happen? how can I extract file itself from `request.data['file']`?

Comment: `WaveFile.objects.create(document=file_obj)` wont work?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I try and there appears the same size file on server!!  but it is broken, I tested some files but every files are broken , same result.

Comment: I opened the file `less`, then find there are unnecessary header `--------------------------b3e7be597652f3cb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="e_h_01.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg`  (binary data from here)

Comment: A small test: remove the parser class and see what happens...

Comment: I use another parser class `MultiPartParser` and it solves.